# How to pass arguments to multiple inherited contracts in Solidity?

Tags: security, inheritance, parameters, solidity, smartcontracts

I have 3 contracts in my project. Contract A inherits from contract B and C. All three contracts A, B, and C take some parameters as the constructor.

How can I pass the arguments of contracts B and C at the same time in the `constructor` of contract A?

My code so far:

```
contract A {
    address public weth;

    constructor(address _weth, address _permit)
        B(_permit, _weth)
        C(_weth)
    {
        weth = _weth;
    }
}
```

The error that I received is `TypeError: Referenced declaration is neither modifier nor base class.`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `is` keyword for extension of parent class.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.21;

contract B {
    constructor(address _permit, address _weth) {}
}

contract C {
    constructor(address _weth) {}
}

// the `is` keyword here
contract A is B, C {
    address public weth;

    constructor(address _weth, address _permit)
        B(_permit, _weth)
        C(_weth)
    {
        weth = _weth;
    }
}
```